# Howto TBB->entry node->middle node->exit node->PROXY->website?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, proxy, privoxy

There was a similar question, but there was no answer. I want to do this: TBB->entry node->middle node->exit node->PROXY->website
At the moment I've got Linux, TBB properly installed, Privoxy properly installed. Tons of read manuals. Google read. Privoxy manuals read.
Please explain what exactly am I to write in Privoxy's config file and how to configure TBB.
If you've experienced another decision with no Privoxy, then please share it.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what your trying to achieve. I don't really understand why would want to have a proxy past the exit node.

Comment: You just want to chain proxies together. There's no native configuration to do this with Privoxy.